# GenericsHelper in spring

Tags: java, spring

Hi can any help me to resolve this issue. Here I create a one JMS bean and then register it and after creating the context final create the spring context using FileSystem.
When I do so it throw an exception saying

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/GenericsHelper
                at org.springframework.beans.PropertyTypeConverter.convertToTypedMap(PropertyTypeConverter.java:316)
```

I am unable to find this class in spring framework. Can some help to solve this issue.I mean from which package this class is coming.

```
 DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();

 BeanDefinition jmsConfigBean = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(Testector.class).addConstructorArg(testApp.getUser().get_empNo()).getBeanDefinition();
                beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("testMessageSelector", jmsConfigBean);

 BeanDefinition jndiEnvironmentBean = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(IRISAssistJndiEnvironment.class).addConstructorArg(irisApp.mode).getBeanDefinition();
                beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("testJndiEnvironment", jndiEnvironmentBean);

 GenericApplicationContext genericContext = new GenericApplicationContext(beanFactory);
 genericContext.refresh();
 new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "Spring_JMS_Config.xml" }, genericContext);
```

Comment: Generally a mixture of jars from different spring versions. Never mix versions of jars of a framework (regardless the framework).

Answer (score 0):

This must be a very old application or [a very old Spring jar](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/springframework/core/GenericsHelper.html) might be in your classpath.

Comment: Yes, this is very old application and I am migrating it to new version. Could you please help to resolve this problem. It will be highly appreciated.